# Verify Evernote API key details

Tags: api-key, evernote

The email account used to generate the API key has been deleted.

I have the API key details but I want to verify they are correct.

How can I verify the API key details? Is it possible without the email account?

Comment: [Ask Evernote](https://dev.evernote.com/).

Comment: The links on their site pushed me here

Comment: Their forum for "Evernote API Discussion" links to Stackoverflow with a filter for Evernote. Here is the [page](https://discussion.evernote.com/forum/163-third-party-application-discussions/).

Comment: Ahh ok. I hope Evernote are paying StackOverflow something for dealing with their API issues. (*This is nothing against you and -in view of your comments- I think you question is fine in that regard*)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/3536236 -- I think significantly less highly of Evernote now I find they throw their tech support over to Stack Overflow `:-/`